# What's a good entry point for The Idolm@ster?

Tags: the-idolmaster

I know that *The Idolm@ster* started out as a raising simulator/rhythm arcade game in Japan, but there is also a bunch of [anime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Idolmaster_media#Anime) and [print media](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Idolmaster_media#Print_media) of it.

Is there a game/anime/manga in English in one form or another (either dubbed or subbed for anime, or officially translated/localized for everything else) which would be a good entry point into the series?

Answer (score 1):

How about [the official YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCe3uJZIjfYwNNR0S6W3GvEA)?
You can watch promotional videos and radio programs for free; original, Million, Cinderella, Shiny, and SideM are all treated. Anime and specials are distributed depending on the time.

Since these are YouTube, most content has auto-generated subtitles; which are somewhat inaccurate, but automatic machine translation is possible. (If you choose English or ’英語’.)

[image: Screenshot of an Idolmaster video on YouTube with Closed Caption setting opened and set to Auto-English]

Of course, these are legal content operated by copyright holders.

Answer (score 1):

I think the 2011 TV anime series is the obvious choice. It corresponds to 2nd Vision games and the classic breakout period while the numbers of idols were still manageable (it has 11, if you count twins as one). The anime that came before was awful. The anime that came after is often a movie, spin-off, or just downright fruity. The 2015 Cinderella Girls series is okay, but not any better than the original.

I read most of iM@S manga and I cannot name one that's definitive.